# Как узнать какому сегменту принадлежит адрес при прямой адресации

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Всем доброго дня,

Я дизассемблирую простую программу в Visual Studio, написанную на C++ под ОС Windows. Там есть такая строка:

```
mov ecx,dword ptr ds:[00A79160h]
```

Инструкция кладет в регистр ECX значение, взятое по адресу `ds:[00A79160h]`. Насколько я понимаю, адрес состоит из селектора сегмента данных, и смещения, значение которого взято по прямому адресу `0х00A79160h`. Но что это за адрес? Как вычисляется физический адрес ячейки `[00A79160h]`? Он ведь также должен принадлежать какому-то сегменту?

Comment: Ваш код в 32битном режиме. Здесь память плоская. И задумываться о сегментах не нужно. Физический адрес ячейки также вряд ли нужен, если только Вы не пишете тестировщик планок памяти.

Comment: Тогда почему адрес значения, помещаемого в ECX начинается с сегмента DS? Или это просто прихоть декомпилятора?

Comment: по простому - сегменты никуда не пропали. Они есть и используются. Вот только прикладному программисту они обычно не нужны. Но дизассемблер студии не может писать совсем по простому, он пишет, как оно есть.

Comment: Т.е. этот прямой адрес всё-таки принадлежит какому-то сегменту, но с точки зрения анализа кода (полноты этого анализа), нам не обязательно знать к какому?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то в 32 битном режиме регистры ds и подобные уже содержать специальное значение, где закодированы уровни привилегий и тому подобное. Поэтому, считайте, что у Вас есть один сегмент на 4 гигабайта.

Comment: Вы правильно написали, что в регистре селектор. но адрес из него не состоит. в защищенном режиме младшие 2 бита селектора - уровень привилегий (скорее всего 3), следующий бит выбирает таблицу дескрипторов (локальная LDT, глобальная GDT) остальные биты - номер элемента дескриптора сегмента в указанной таблице. А вот уже в дескрипторной таблице написан базовый адрес сегмента в физической памяти и смещение указано относительно него. И то не совсем в физической, в виртуальной конечно, потому что есть еще страничное преобразование